# How to get and set a textView text (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gtk#

I have to make a code that will take a text from textView and append text to it.
But, unfortunately, my code does not work. It literally does nothing
Here is what I have made:

```
private void btnClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        txtViewOne.Text += "0";

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in android you can do it just like this without using any Build in functions

```
 txtViewOne.setText(txtViewOne.getText()+"0");
```

or to store the appended value to any String

```
String appendedString=txtViewOne.getText()+"0";
```

in c# same

```
txtViewOne.Text=txtViewOne.Text+"0";
```

> and do not use the += operator. it will not work on Strings. it is an
>   arithmetic operator

Comment: I use Xamarin.Forms not Android Studio

Comment: i just added the c# code also.... and please dont use the android tag if your question is not from android

Answer (score 0):

You can just write as below it'll work

```
private void btnClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            txtViewOne.Text =txtViewOne.Text + "0";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in solution, try TextView.Append()

developer.xamarin.com -> api -> Android.Widget.TextView.Append(System.String)

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)